# LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter and emojis

Tags: regex, flutter

When I use a LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter in a flutter text field and type emojis in some of them count as 3 characters. This allows the char counter to go past the limit, e.g. 275/250.

I have tried to print the counter myself using this

```
child: Text("${Characters(messageController.text).length}/$maxCharacters", style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),
```

which keeps it as 1 character but it still doesnt allow me to input 250 emojis. 
One of the emojis that is counting as 3 is ️.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In fact emojis length's more than one.if you need count each emoji as one char you can use regular expressions.

```
void main() {
RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"([\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\u2694-\u2697]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDD5D])");
    String str = "Hello ️️️️️️️ there";
Iterable<Match> matches = exp.allMatches(str);
int emojiLength=0;
matches.forEach((m)=>emojiLength+=m.group(0).length);
print(str.length-emojiLength+matches.length);
}
```

response is 19

Comment: How do i get the LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter  to do that?